# Как посчить эти переменные?

Tags: javascript

```
 var a = number; // тут у нас число
 var b = secondnumber; // тут у нас второе число
 var action = '+'; //действие допустим добавление
 var result = a + action + b; // сделаем пример 1 + 1
 console.log(result); //результат выведет нам 1+1, а вместо этого нам нужно 2!
```

Как можно реализовать именно математическое действие а не просто складывать текст вместе? Тема вроде простая но не могу понять в чем дело, буду благодарен вашей помощи!

Comment: в javascript есть функция [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) позволяющая выполнять произвольный код. Без ее использования, точно так же как и в любом другом языке: с помощью разбора выражения, либо как в ответе ниже сразу проверять знак и выполнять соответствующую функцию

Answer (score 2):

Что-то вроде такого

```
var operation = {
    '+' : function( a, b ) { return a + b; }
};

var a = number; // тут у нас число
var b = secondnumber; // тут у нас второе число
var action = '+'; //действие допустим добавление
var result = operation[action]( a, b ); // сделаем пример 1 + 1
console.log(result); //результат выведет 2
```

Вот пример страницы с предложенным решением.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test of operation plus</h1>
    <script>
        window.onload = function (firstNumber, secondNumber) {
            var operation =
            {
                "+": function (a, b) { return a + b; }
            };
            var a = firstNumber;
            var b = secondNumber;
            var action = "+";
            var result = operation[action](a, b);
            alert(result);
        }(1, 2);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

В `alert` выводит число `3`.

Comment: Само по себе оно работает, а внутри функции почему то нет (

Comment: Вот что получилось https://jsfiddle.net/y7vt5hpc/ но почему не работает?

Comment: @arthru  А что это за строка 'How much is *number *action *secondnumber': function(number, action, secondnumber) {

Comment: @arthru Смотрите мой дополненный примером ответ.

Comment: Просто я балуюсь с голосовыми командами, и у меня получается идет как список функций и по этому нужно что бы все происходило внутри функции

Comment: ПО сути можно внутри самих var a и var b написать именно цифры (потому что это то что там храниться) но все равно не делает именно тогда математику, потому что мы не можешь вызывать за пределами функции

Comment: Вот нужно что то такое (не рабочая версия) - https://jsfiddle.net/sLnfe9pm/

Comment: @arthru Я вам привел пример скрипта. Он работает. Так что творите!:) Если есть другие проблемы, то лучше задать новый вопрос, так как обычно читают вопросы и ответы, а не многочисленные комментарии.